# Websites Appearing on Server but not rest of Network

Tags: domain-name-system

We have a setup in which IIS is working properly if remoted into the server.  On the actual sever, it is working with both with ip addresses and dns.

If, however, I am on a client machine on the same network, many of the same ip/port combos and cnames/anames don't resolve in internet explorer and Mozilla.  'This page can't be displayed.'  But I am logged into the network so in theory it should work.  I can ping these websites and tracert them too.

Where should I start troubleshooting?

Comment: What says `nslookup dontworkingname` from client ?

Comment: `I am logged into the network so in theory it should work` - Being connected to the same network doesn't mean that the web sites should load on other computers. The other computers need a name resolution mechanism in order to resolve the server/site names. What are you using for name resolution on the network?

Comment: I am not sure, but the same domain names DO work for directory browsing and remote desktop.  They only don't work for internet explorer and mozilla.

how do  find out about the name resolution?